# Symfony 4 CollectionType with multiple drop downs with default values

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have created a form but now I need to add 7 drops downs as an array and they will be stored serialised in the OpenTimes param of my entity. I have done similar with ChoiceType for checkboxes and that works.

I can't work out how I can make 7 different drops downs using CollectionType, they just don't show up on the form.

```
$form->add('openTimes',CollectionType::class,[
            'entry_type'=>ChoiceType::class,
            'entry_options'=>[
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'form-control selectpicker'
                ],
                'choices'=>[
                    '9:00'=>'9:00',
                    '10:00'=>'10:00'

                ]
            ]

        ]);
```

This code clearly doesn't work and it's not exactly what i need.

I need 7 drop downs in an array so one will be Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc and the drop down will contain times of the day such as 9am, 10am etc.

The code above even if it did work is going to duplicate them with the same choices which is fine, but they are not showing up on the form and  i'm not sure how i would tell the form to name them like this:

```
<select name="openTimes[mon]">
<select name="openTimes[tue]">
```

So my questions are:

1. How do I get this collection of drop downs to actually show on the form when i use {{form_widget(form.openTimes)}}
2. How do I make each select element name it how I want as the day of the week as the array key?

Comment: How are you defining the underlying data structure for `openTimes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should dump serialized data logic, but if you really want to do everything in that matter, use JSON data type as doctrine supports it. For converting data the way you want you can use Data Transformers. As for Form rendering you should create your own custom Form Type for example "OpenTimeType" where elements will be "WeekDay" and "Hour" and then in your main form you can create collection named "OpenTimes" of your form type "OpenTimeType".

Comment: Ah so it needs to be done via a custom type, brilliant, thanks!